# ИИ нужно больше мозгов

Tags: предложение, блокировка

С аккаунта [stackflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/259379/stackflow) с утра шел безостановочный бред в вопросах. Плюс к этому создавалось много новых меток, см. скрины в самом низу.

Эти вопросы минусовались участниками, но автоматическая система сайта никак не реагировала на такое поведение с этого аккаунта, кроме как понижением репутации.

Предлагаю ИИ добавить больше мозгов ;)

---

Скриншоты прьвью вопросов:

> [image: вопросы (часть 1)]
>
> [image: вопросы (часть 2)]

Comment: по идее, если много вопросов подряд с большим количеством минусов, должна блокироваться возможность задать вопрос. Автор перестал задавать вопросы спустя некоторое время, но возможно сработала блокировка из-за флагов. Будет хорошо если Николас напишет о текущих алгоритмах для блокировки.